# An algorithm to find an orthogonal path between two 10 digit numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, math, graph-theory

Let **S** be a set of 10 digit numbers. Given any two numbers **v** and **w** in **S**, I'd like to know if there is a sequence of numbers **v=u_0, u_1, ... , u_k=w** such that:

1. each **u_i** is in **S**
2. for each **i=1,..,k**, the numbers **u_{i-1}** and **u_i** differ in exactly one position

As a plus, it would be even better to find an algorithm to find the shortest such sequence.

Ideally, I would prefer a C (or pseudo-code) solution, but I *really, really* appreciate any and all suggestions on this one! Thanks!

Comment: If you folks voting to close would give me a hint as to why you're doing so, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: There are currently 2 votes to close this as "not being a real question", probably because it's too open. It's not a programming question, it's more of a question for someone to provide you with an algorithm.

Comment: I'd imagine it is because there is no code and is a high level algorithm question. But I'm not a downvoter. My suggestion would be a breadth first search, or A*.

Comment: This is silly. Just because people don't understand the terms, they try to close it. This just seems like a graph problem of finding shortest paths.

Comment: What programming puzzle is this? It's a bit unnatural to model this using digits in a number, standard would be to use vectors.

Comment: I had vectors, but thought the questions sounded too complicated. I really want to do this for an n-dimension vector space over a finite field.

Comment: Should have mentioned that. I've been trying all day to come up with a clever approach to check whether two numbers differ by exactly one digit.

Comment: Hey, I'd LOVE to hear it if you have an answer. By working in base p (over F_p), this is exactly the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form a graph from elements of S: u and v are adjacent iff they differ in exactly one coordinate.

Now given u, do a breadth first search till you hit v.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert `S` to a graph of node objects, where each node object contains links to the adjacent nodes.  (In some programming languages, read 'links' as 'pointers'.)  Adjacency is defined by your condition 2 on the sequence, so that any path through the resulting graph is a sequence matching the two conditions.

From there, it's a simple problem of checking for connectedness of two vertices in your graph.  The simplest solution is a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).  (That particular algorithm also happens to find the shortest path(s).)